# Mean square of a random variable is bounded

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of random variables and in $L^2.$

Suppose the existence of $M$ such that for all $n$ we have $$P(X^2_n\ge M)<P(X^2_n\ge E(X^2_n)),$$

Does it follow that $E(X_n^2)\le M$ for all $n$ ?

I tried to find a counter exemple but I didn't succeed, and for a proof if it is correct I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general if $Z$ is a random variable and $a,b\in\mathbb R$ then: $$P(Z\geq a)<P(Z\geq b)\implies b<a\tag1$$

Observe that: $$b\geq a\implies P(Z\geq a)=P(Z\in[a,b))+P(Z\geq b)\geq P(Z\geq b)$$
Taking the contrapositive of that we find $(1)$.

Comment: so simple...thank you !